# jQuery .accordion Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am attempting to use .accordion however it does not seem to be working. Here is what I have in my head:

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    })
</script>
```

And this is what I have in my body:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <h1>This is an According Example</h1>
    <div id="accordion" style="width:1024px;">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please Help!
This is an edit:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () 
        { $(document).ready(function () 
            { $("#accordion").accordion(); 
        }) 
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>This is an According Example</h1>
    <div id="accordion" style="width:1024px;">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeA2I.png)

Comment: it works fine ..http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/c1hotu9a/2/  try to close </div> for <div id="mainContent">

Comment: I did close it, it is at the bottom. Should it be next to it instead?

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is you run `.arcordion()` before the HTML is loaded. You have to call it after the Elements where created in DOM:

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

And this is what I have in my body:
<div id="mainContent">
    <h1>This is an According Example</h1>
    <div id="accordion" style="width:1024px;">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    })
</script>
```

However the standard way would be to do it when the dom has loaded, via `window.onload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        })
    }
</script>
```

Demo:

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload =  function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        })
    }
</script>

And this is what I have in my body:
<div id="mainContent">
    <h1>This is an According Example</h1>
    <div id="accordion" style="width:1024px;">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just now added that in place for the previous script but it still isn't showing up like how the code looks in the "run code snippet" it just looks like sentences with underlines under some of them. Is it because I'm on chrome?

Comment: Wich one did you try in your code? For some reason `addEventListener` might not work, use `window.onload =  function () {` as in the demo code

Comment: I was using the first one but then I just switched to that one and it still isn't working.

Comment: <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        })
    }
</script>

Comment: <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>This is an According Example</h1>
    <div id="accordion" style="width:1024px;">
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for first sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the first sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for second sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the second sentence.</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Heading for third sentence</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is the third sentence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: you are missing the `=`  in  `window.onload = function() {` and you have weird `(` there as well

Comment: window.onload = function () { $(document).ready(function () { $("#accordion").accordion(); }) }

Comment: when I do that it only adds it to the top of the webpage as text

Comment: <script>window.onload = function () { $(document).ready(function () { $("#accordion").accordion(); }) }</script>

Comment: can you post you complete code somewhere? Because like this it has to work, there must be sth else

Comment: I just posted it under "This is an edit:" next to "Please Help!"

Comment: Okay, I posted a picture of what it looks like on my mac. Thank you for all your help I really have no clue why this isn't working for me!

Comment: for some reason you where not using `http:` in your links!!! When loading it as a local file this will not work.. use it like: `<link href="http://...` see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

This is the markup for your accordion:

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Section #1</a>
                <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? </p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Section #2</a>
                <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">Section #3</a>
                <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. </p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-->
    </div>
```

Add this to your css:

```
.accordion, .accordion * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.accordion {
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}

/*----- Section Titles -----*/
.accordion-section-title {
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;
    background:#333;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    /* Type */
    font-size:1.200em;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
    color:#fff;
}

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
    background:#4c4c4c;
    /* Type */
    text-decoration:none;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
    border-bottom:none;
}

/*----- Section Content -----*/
.accordion-section-content {
    padding:15px;
    display:none;
}
```

This is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            // Add active class to section title
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            jQuery('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

See the example in the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/81tqnuj9/